# Unable to validate ASP.NET framework web API with Google Bearer token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization

Steps I have followed:

1. Create a project in Google API console and also enabled Google+
   API.
2. Fetch client API and client secret.
3. Uncomment code and replace the appropriate value in the code:

   [image]
4. Fetch Authorization token using Angular6 after sign in to Google.
5. While Calling API from postman getting the following error:

   > "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request.

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post text (code, errors, etc.)